# Laravel Eloquent Latest Status From Log Table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have an `order_status_transaction` table which is a log table for recording the status of transactions

[image]

I am trying to write an eloquent builder to get all of the transactions with a CURRENT status of **5** for example.

This is the closest I have got

```
$transactions = $this->whereHas('statuses', function ($query) use ($statusId) {
    $query->where('order_status_transaction.order_status_id', $statusId)->where();
});
```

But it does not check if it is the most recent. I don't want to get the collection and filter the collection, can this be going purely in a builder?

Comment: The `statuses` you have in `$this->whereHas('statuses',` which table does it belong to?

Answer (score 0):

This should do

`$transactions = OrderStatusTransaction::where('order_status_id', $statusId)->latest()->get();`

Assuming `OrderStatusTransaction` as your model name.
As in the comments, latest sorts by latest.

Comment: while your suggestion is a good one it does not answer the question of getting the most recent record first

Answer (score -1):

Query builder has a method called `latest()` and so you would write something like this:

```
OrderStatusTransaction::where('order_status_id', $statusId)
    ->latest()
    ->get();
```

This will get all the records with the given status id going from most recent first to oldest.

You can read me about this here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset